# How to select the cell from middle column in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have odd number of columns and want to select value from the middle one, how?

Example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
A B C D E F G
```

How to select the cell "D"?

Comment: What ő you mean by select? Make the cell active? Or have a formula in another cell returning its value? Which version of Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula would return the value of the middle column of a range of cells. This formula assumes your data is in row 1 of the sheet (specified after "ADDRESS" in the formula). The range of cells to be assessed is shown after "COLUMNS" in the formula.

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,ROUNDUP((COLUMNS(A1:G1)/2),0)))`

Comment: This does't works properly if use for C1:I1 you get 2,, if for G1:M1 returns 0,,  Even the array formula doesn't works  !!

Comment: @RajeshS The assumption is that columns commence at column A and not partway across the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly, what I was looking for!

Comment: @JasonRiley,,,yes it was my concern,, that a efficient formula has to work every where,,,, it needs improvisation !!

Comment: @RajeshS It fits the use case and satisfies the requirements of the requestor. There's no point buying a Ferrari if all you need is a bicycle. However, you may wish to work on it further so that the formula can reference columns other than those beginning at the left of the sheet.

Comment: @JasonRiley,,, here I've solved so many puzzles, and I solve this one also,, but since you have posted the solution so that I'm expecting you to correct it so that this may work anywhere in the sheet.  A good solution has to work in all circumstances !!